# Add #y to the end of the string if it contains x

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following contents:

```
# cat.txt
AB-1 text: foo
AB-1 test3: test cat dog
AB-1 test4: abc

# cat2.txt
AB-4 test: qwerty
AB-5 test2: Foo bar
AB-6 abc: Dog
```

and try to get the following from it, if the string contains `x` then add `#y` to its end:

```
# cat.txt
AB-1 text: foo#foo #text 
AB-1 test3: test cat dog#animal 
AB-1 test4: abc

# cat2.txt
AB-4 test: qwerty
AB-5 test2: Foo bar#foo 
AB-6 abc: Dog#animal
```

I ran into the following problems:

- ignore strings starting with #
- two keywords in one line is possible
- case sensitive

I solved the last two points, but not sure if it is logical and proper, anaway:

`awk '{print $0 (tolower($0) ~ /foo/ ? "#foo " : "" ) (tolower($0) ~ /cat|dog/ ? "#animal " : "") (tolower($0) ~ /text/ ? "#text " : "")}' ./file.txt`

Thus, at this point is the following result:

```
# cat.txt#animal 
AB-1 text: foo#foo #text 
AB-1 test3: test cat dog#animal 
AB-1 test4: abc

# cat2.txt#animal 
AB-4 test: qwerty
AB-5 test2: Foo bar#foo 
AB-6 abc: Dog#animal
```

The result is pretty close to what is needed, but the following points still cause concern:

- As you can see i am using `tolower($0) ~` to make the concept case insensitive. I use macOS and have not succeeded using `-v IGNORECASE=1` flag or `BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}`, for some reason it also does not work in my concept. Is it possible to improve this?
- Is there any way to ignore strings that start with #?

Comment: What is **the string** in the sentence `if the string contains x then add #y to its end`? Is it the whole line or just the part of the line after the first `:` or individual space-separated words after the first `:` or something else? If `foobar` existed in the input should that match `foo` or not? If it did, should it become `foo#bar` or `foobar#` or something else? When you say `ignore strings starting with #` - do you really mean `ignore lines starting with #` or can `#` appear mid-line?

Comment: Regarding `I use macOS and have not succeeded using -v IGNORECASE=1` - right, `IGNORECASE` is a GNU awk extension, it's not part of POSIX and not part of the BSD awk that's the default on MacOS. Install GNU awk if you want it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk '/^#/ {   # if line starts with #
   print      # print it
   next       # skip to next line
}
{
   lcr = tolower($0)
   print $0 (lcr ~ /foo/ ? "#foo " : "" ) \
   (lcr ~ /cat|dog/ ? "#animal " : "") (lcr ~ /text/ ? "#text " : "")
}' file

# cat.txt
AB-1 text: foo#foo #text
AB-1 test3: test cat dog#animal
AB-1 test4: abc

# cat2.txt
AB-4 test: qwerty
AB-5 test2: Foo bar#foo
AB-6 abc: Dog#animal
```

Comment: yes, thx! currently trying to solve the matter with case sensitive.

Comment: But `tolower` already solves it, why do you need gnu-awk `IGNORECASE` now?

Comment: right, `tolower` works, but don't know if it's a good idea to call it every time instead of one time.

Comment: Have removed multiple `tolower` calls now

Answer (score 0):

> macOS and have not succeeded using `-v IGNORECASE=1` flag or
> `BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}`, for some reason it also does not work in my
> concept. Is it possible to improve this?

[`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) is GNU `AWK` specific feature, so if this does not work on your machine you are not using GNU `AWK`. Use `awk --version` to detect what version of AWK are you actually using. [macappstore.org](https://macappstore.org/gawk/) suggest that there exist `gawk` for MacOS, but I do not have ability to test it.

Comment: awk version 20200816